# Facebook publish stream directly using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to publish stream on my facebook WEBSITE wall page.

so far I succeeded to publish stream via my APP page but I dont want via, I want to publish directly.

as I said before, I want to publish on my facebook WEBSITE wall page, not on the app wall page.

I couldnt find anything useful... also I want to publish with PHP if thats possible.. if it is not possible than I guess I will have to use js. anyway how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how I do it with PHP :

```
 //Note that you will need to have the access token which is what gives permission to write.
 function self_fb_post($to_uid,$acToken) {
    global $fb; //this is the fb object
    $result = false;
    $feed_dir = '/'.$to_uid.'/feed/';  //to the UID you want to send to
    $message_str =  'Why does facebook development not have decent support';
    $msg_body = array('access_token' => $acToken,   
                  'name' => 'My wall post',
                  'message' => $message_str,
                  'caption' => "www.mysite.com",
                  'link' => 'http://www.mysite.com',
                  'description' => 'A wall post which is used to express the frustration of working with crappy facebook developer documentation', 
                  'picture' => 'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/1111/some-pic.jpg',
                  'actions' => array(array('name' => 'My Site',
                              'link' => 'http://www.mysite.com'))
                  );

try {
            //this is the API call that does it all
    $result = $fb->api($feed_dir, 'post', $msg_body);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {       
    $err_str = $e->getMessage();
}


     return $result;
}
```

Comment: I included (by using require) the facebook.php (sdk), used the function sent $acToken as access token and $to_uid as id of the website page. Is this right? because it didnt work for me

Comment: The $to_uid is the Facebook user id of the person who's wall you want to post to (be it your own or someone elses).

Comment: well I tried three different ids > app id, website wall id and my user id, nothing worked... btw I used this example to get the info > https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: What error are you getting? maybe the access token is not being set right... this works fine for me. In my case I am getting both the access token and uid from my database.

Comment: I dont get any error.. its like not running the function at all

Comment: echo($result); will show the result of the post attempt.. put this somewhere

Comment: used var_dump because echo cant work with boolean. I put the var_dump after the try catch and it return nothing. if I put before the try catch it return false as it should be. its like getting stuck in the try catch...

Comment: It doesnt reach the catch. it gets stuck here $result = $fb->api($feed_dir, 'post', $msg_body); - that means I am using wrong accesstoken / uid which I dont think so or I use the wrong sdk, I dont think so too coz I downloaded it from facebook (github)..

Comment: Is your facebook object called $fb ? this is just what I named mine so make sure you are using the same one. require_once("path_to/facebook.php");
$fb= new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'Your app id',
   'secret' => 'your secret key',
   'cookie' => true,
 ));

Comment: I forgot to put this line in the code $fb= new Facebook(array( 'appId' => 'Your app id', 'secret' => 'your secret key', 'cookie' => true, ));. After I added it, it wokrd. but still it post VIA my account and directly...

Comment: what do you mean by "VIA my account" ? who/what do you want to be the poster?

Comment: I want that the app it self will be the poster

Comment: So you need to use an access token that belongs to your app

Comment: Used this url to get the application access token > https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
     grant_type=client_credentials and I recieved error using ur script: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

Comment: In order for an application to make a post on behalf of the user, a user must authorize the application. In your case the application will need to ask for the permissions: publish_stream and offline_access . These permissions will give you the ability to use the users access tokens to make posts in their via them.

Comment: I got permissions and still it doesnt work. Used this url to give the premissions > http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=APIKEY&connect_display=popup&v=1.0&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&cancel_url=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failure.html&fbconnect=true&return_session=true&req_perms=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access replaced with my APIKEY ofcourse. is it right? and if it is why it still not working? (I also added the app to my favorites) [same error]

Comment: You need to initiate the facebook session as the APP and than pass $fb->getAccessToken() as the access token. So just to clarify, do not initiate the session as the user in some kind of client script! it should be something like a script run on a server with a session initiated as the app.

Comment: Ok, I am using the app access token and still it writes to me the same error. I tried to post on the app's wall and it works, but I want to write in other wall > website wall and there I get the error...

Comment: Yes you get that error because the user/site you are trying to post to "hasn't authorized the application to perform this action". Meaning the user/site did not give your app publish_stream and offline_access permissions.

Comment: Because site cnnt give permissions to application... or is it possible? I gave the permission to the app by the user, not by the site...

Comment: ? im not sure what you mean here.

Comment: You said that I got the error because I didnt give to the app publish_stream and offline_access permissions but I did give the permissions using my user not the site..

Comment: When you say site what do you mean?

Comment: When I say site I mean that if you'll write the name of the page in the facebook search u will find two DIFFERENT results one with "App" title and one with "Website" title. I want to publish from the app to the website - both were made by me and both have walls [every wall is different].

Comment: So in this case the site will have its own UID which will need to be the thing giving permissions.. im guessing though since I have not tried this.

Comment: I belive this is impossilbe to give permissions with the "website" because it is not user or something. Yes it has its own UID but I couldnt find how to give permissions using its UID.

Comment: What happens when you are logged into facebook as the website and than add the app?

Comment: It asks me to go back to my user or else I wont be able to watch the page.