# Use an HTML form to take data and post that on Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to set up a site so a user can type a comment in an HTML form and that comment will then be placed on that person's wall after pressing the submit button.

I have already set up the publish_stream permission and can publish easily to a stream using the method shown here: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301358/facebook-publish-stream-directly-using-php?tab=active#tab-top)

However, if you use an HTML form and press submit, the page will reload and go through the token acquisition process. This results in some re-routing that causes the data in $_REQUEST to be lost.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [post message to facebook from <textarea> using fb.ui?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305745/post-message-to-facebook-from-textarea-using-fb-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Yup dear you can use it using java script.

```
<textarea id="status" cols="50" rows="5">Write your status here and click 'Status Set Using Legacy Api Call'</textarea>
<br />
<a href="#" onClick="setStatus(); return false;">Status Set Using JSDK Call</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({appId: 'Your APPI ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

                /* All the events registered */
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    // do something with response
                    //login();
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                    // do something with response
                    //logout();
                });

                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    if (response.session) {
                        // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                       // login();
                    }
                });
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
function setStatus(){
                status1 = document.getElementById('status').value;
                FB.api(
                  {
                    method: 'status.set',
                    status: status1
                  },
                  function(response) {
                    if (response == 0){
                        alert('Your facebook status not updated. Give Status Update Permission.');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Your facebook status updated');
                    }
                  }
                );
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Awais!So is it not possible to handle forms in an iframe? What if I want to use forms to embed a survey into my application?

Comment: How do you ensure that the data is sent from the form though? Lets say I have <form action=index.php>, so the form get's handled by the index page itself (include some hidden field and check if(isset($_REQUEST["hidden"]). The problem I am having is that none of the form data is being sent back to index.php after I press the submit button.

Comment: Ok place your all code and edit your question and let me know after that