# Facebook auto post on wall after like

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

So basically i am building a script for a client which is used as an iframe in his page. What it should do is when a user likes his page then he can see the contents and the "app" should auto post something to his wall (sounds like spam but im not sure if there is a problem with that). so i got the first bit working but for the love of god i cant make the second part.. here's my code

```
<? require 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "my_appid";
$app_secret = "my_secret";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
function parsePageSignedRequest() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false;
  }
  if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
    if($signed_request->page->liked) {
      echo "This content is for Fans only!";    
    } else {
      echo "Please click on the Like button to view this tab!";
    }
  }

?>
```

i tried adding this on the "logged state"

```
$result = $facebook->api( '/me/feed/','post',
        array('access_token' => $app_secret,
              'message' => 'Playing around with FB Graph..')
    );
```

with no luck as i get an error. please let me know if you can help. thanx

Comment: access_token != app_secret, and you need permission from the user (publish_stream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part, liking a url and autoposting to users stream has nothing todo with the code you show. this code is just a simple fan gateway.

no user is logedin.

The steps you would need are:

- let the user login and ask for publish_stream permission ([more info](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/))
- set a listener on the edge.create event ([more info](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/))

  - if this event fires send an ajax call to server to make the post. ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301358/facebook-publish-stream-directly-using-php))

Comment: So the only way is to get the users permitions first.ok that was helpfull. the purpose of this was supposed as i understand if from the requirements given is to post something without the users accepting anything but it seems that it cant be done. Does any one have any idea if aytomatically posts are considered spam on facebook? thanx

Comment: in my experience, the percentage of users which accept the permission is lower with any additional permissions you ask for. the publish_stream is one of the permissions which less people are willing to give.

Comment: if it would be possible to post to stream without the user wanting/knowing and dont have to ask permissions for, facebook would be a place full of spam. in many of my apps i present the user just with the standard facebook (js sdk) fb.ui publish.stream dialog. i dont need rights for it to display, and the user just has to klick send if he want. or can close it if not.

Comment: i think i found a sample code for this but would be glad if you can post my a sample of your solution:)